# ASP.NET Web API not getting newly posted item

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am learning how the ASP.NET Web API works because I need it for a project I am working on. I am using OWIN to host the Web API inside a WPF application.

I am having trouble getting my POST method to work. When I POST a new product it is being added to the products list but when I try to GET all products, it does not show up.

This is a class I am using to test it out:

```
class Program
    {
        const string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                RunAsync().Wait();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //GET initial products
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() + "\n");
                }

                //POST new product
                Product gizmo = new Product() { Id = 4, Name = "Gizmo", Price = 50, Category = "Widget"};
                try
                {
                    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", gizmo);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                //GET all products (should contain gizmo product)
                response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my Controller class:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

        public ProductsController()
        {
            products.Add(new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 });
            products.Add(new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M });
            products.Add(new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M });
        }

        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(product);
        }

        public void Post(Product product) {
            products.Add(product);
            Console.WriteLine("Product Added: " + products[products.Count - 1].Name + "\n");
        }
    }
```

The output is showing that the new Gizmo item is added to the list:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato Soup","Category":"Groceries","Price":1.0},{"Id":2,"Name":"Yo-yo","Category":"Toys","Price":3.75},{"Id":3,"Name":"Hammer","Category":"Hardware","Price":16.99}]

Product Added: Gizmo

[{"Id":1,"Name":"Tomato Soup","Category":"Groceries","Price":1.0},{"Id":2,"Name":"Yo-yo","Category":"Toys","Price":3.75},{"Id":3,"Name":"Hammer","Category":"Hardware","Price":16.99}]
```

Comment: Does your controller constructor get called for every request?

Comment: @Brendan Yes the constructor is being called every request, which makes sense now you mentioned it. I changed the way I was initializing the list and it is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller constructor is likely being called for every request (remember, HTTP is stateless).

Use a persistent store for your `List<Product>`.